# how does 頑張ってかないと work？

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances

> 「開き直ってさ」
> 「開き直れないよ、北村君は見てるんだもん」
>  `「だからこそ頑張ってかないとだろう」`

Aside from the meaning (which I think I understand), I don’t have the slightest idea about the structure of the last part `かないとだろう`. tried searching a few places but didn’t get any results. could you please explain where this is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

頑張ってかないとだろう = 頑張っていかないとならないだろう

～ないと・なくては・なければ are often short for ～ないと・なくては・なければ　だめ・いけない・ならない, with ～なくては and なければ often contracting to ～なくちゃ and ～なきゃ. Additionaly, ～ていく is often pronounced as ～てく in speech.